# Iterate two lists Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, list-comprehension

I have this function:

```
applyRel :: (Eq k) => k -> (BinaryRelation k v) -> [v] 
applyRel key list = [ v | (k,v)<-list, key==k]
```

and it takes a string, k and returns all v's with the given k:

> applyRel "bar" bar_stuff

would output

> ["mitzva", "stool", "tender", "keeper"]

And it works, but what if it takes in a list of strings and another list.
Can I do something like a list recursion the iterates through a list and for each item iterates through the second list. Kinda of like a double for loop in C.

This is what I'm kind of going towards:

```
applyToList :: [k] -> (BinaryRelation k v) -> [v]
applyToList [] list = []
applyToList keys list = 
     do key <- keys
        applyRel key list
```

Comment: The input for the second code would look like:
applyToList ["salad","bar"] bar_stuff)
and output:
["bar", "mitzva", "stool", "tender", "keeper"]

Comment: Your code should work if you add the `Eq k` constraint to `applyToList`. You also don't need the first clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already works if you add the `Eq k` constraint to `applyToList`:

```
applyToList :: Eq k => [k] -> BinaryRelation k v -> [v]
applyToList keys list = do
    key <- keys
    applyRel key list
```

You can also leave out the pattern match on `[]`.  Example of it working:

```
> let bar_stuff = [("bar", "mitzva"), ("bar", "stool"), ("bar", "tender"), ("bar", "keeper"), ("salad", "bar"), ("foo", "bar")]
> applyToList ["salad", "bar"] bar_stuff
["bar","mitzva","stool","tender","keeper"]
```

Or you could just use `concatMap`, which is used in the instance of `Monad` for lists anyway:

```
applyToList :: Eq k => [k] -> BinaryRelation k v -> [v]
applyToList keys list = concatMap (flip applyRel list) keys
```